# How to set up login view (user authentication) in SPA HotTowel template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, breeze, single-page-application, durandal, hottowel

Some of the Single Page Application (SPA) templates in VS2012 MVC4 have built-in authentication. HotTowel SPA Template does not.

What is the proper way to implement user authentication (login screen) in SPA HotTowel?
HotTowel uses Durandal JS, so I guess the question is really how to implement user authentication with Durandal JS

Comment: What kind of authentication you looking for?

Comment: As Simple, as it can be. Just to authenticate the users against database saved user names and passwords. After successful login the SPA will load.

Comment: I was thinking about the security too. The usage of [ValidateAntuForgeryToken] with the Breeze.js controller, but this is a part of another question.

Comment: i would just use basic auth then.  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

Answer (score 12):

I created a starter template with authentication and authorization included

Perhaps could help ...

Github => https://github.com/yagopv/durandalauth

Sample site => https://durandalauth.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: in your durandalauth app, how did you managed to save json web token? Is it using asp.net sessions or client-side cookie ?

Comment: It uses local or session storage. If you take a look to https://github.com/yagopv/DurandalAuth/blob/master/DurandalAuth.Web/App/services/appsecurity.js, you can see the details. 
The following functions take care about managing the local storage [getSecurityHeaders(), setAccessToken(accessToken, persistent), clearAccessToken()].
You should include the headers in each ajax request using getSecurityHeaders(). Bye!!

Comment: Looking over your stuff, do you want a hard coded user and password for your database in web.config? 

Also you might want to include the database creation scripts so we can run on our own database :)

Nice stuff so far otherwise.

Comment: Ignore my last bit about database scripts, just found the entity migrations.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the Durandal JS Google group have some answers but not concrete sample code.

[Authentication with Durandal](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/durandaljs/user%2420authentication/durandaljs/mtzMnEXzfvg/JPHWz2ZQHRYJ)

[Looking to add authentication to the SPA sample, but keep it an SPA](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/durandaljs/user%2420authentication/durandaljs/0RkoNHMKjJA/6DKDqcdEgY0J)

Mauro Servienti ideas:

My backend exposes a service (WebAPI in my case) where there is an operation getCurrentUser.

So, in my main.js, in the app.Start() then callback before calling app.setRoot I issue a call the backend asking, async, for the user if the result is a valid user I set the root to the main app shell otherwise I set the root to the login shell.

What is the problem? From the client side point of view the authentication is just a “flag” that says: ok, I know who you are. You can leverage the power of the FormsAuthentication and live with that, then expose a WebAPI GET action that let you retrieve info about the currently logged user.

Answer (score 0):

As John Papa would say, HotTowel is just a template :). In fact, in his 2nd course about SPA in Pluralsight, he creates the application from scratch.

Wouldn't be enough to start your app from a SPA template and then add the rest of libraries HotTowel has (Durandal, Breeze, etc)?

You can see the comparison here [asp.net spa templates](http://www.johnpapa.net/asp-net-spa-templates/)